# hide actual url in status bar when a link or actionlink is mouseovered or clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, actionlink

I want to hide the actual url that is displayed in status bar of browser when link or actionlink is mouseovered or clicked. I tried using `window.status` but it is not working. Also the examples that i saw were for fixed urls to some sites. But the links that i want hide in status bar are like `/Home/DownloadFileUsingFileName?FileName=Filename` in which `Filename`will be different for different files based on their name.

Edit:
The duplicate question deals with `<a href="url">Hyperlink</a>` but i am working with actionlinks. And i want a solution to hide url in status bar when an action link is clicked.

Comment: Based off what the dupe says `<a href="#" data-href="/Home/DownloadFileUsingFileName?FileName=Filename">XXX</a>` and `$("a").on("click", function(){
   this.href = $(this).data("href"); 
});`

Comment: I got the solution for <a href></a> and thanks for that but i also want a solution for actionlinks.

Comment: And what  does an action link render as since that is not an html element.

Comment: `$(function(){ $("a").each(function(){ $(this).data("href", this.href); this.href="#"; }).on("click", function(){ this.href = $(this).data("href");  }); });`

Comment: Any web page that tries to hide the status bar and its contents is immediately suspect and wouldn't be visited again by me.  Why do you need to hide this? What are you hiding?  Do you really think you can hide something?  Surprised this doesn't have the downvotes like all all the duplicates have.